# NestJs returns 404 on all routes when deployed with nginx but locally everything works well

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, jenkins, nestjs

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CoreConfig } from './config.const';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { NestApplicationOptions } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const httpOptions ={
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
  };
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .addServer(`http://localhost:${CoreConfig.app.port}`)
    .setTitle('test UI/AI')
    .setDescription('UI meta service')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('test')
    .addBearerAuth({type:'http', bearerFormat: 'authorization'})
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);
  app.enableCors();
  app.setGlobalPrefix('ui');
  await app.listen(CoreConfig.app.port);
}

bootstrap().then();
```

When my app is deployed with nginx, we have a prefix for routing to this NestJs app (UI) all requests end with 404, however locally everything works well.

Here is the result from instance deployed

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Cannot GET /ui/"}
```

And locally http://prntscr.com/uk2dgj

Comment: If this behaves differently with an Nginx proxy and in Docker, can you edit the question to include the relevant Nginx and Docker configurations?  What URL path are you trying to fetch?

Comment: It seems like to be a issue from nginx routing and how your application is set up on the production env.

Answer (score 6):

I configured ingress-nginx to send all traffic visiting `/api/` over to my backend (NestJS app).

The issue was that the `/api/` part was being sent to my NestJS app and none of those routes existed. For example my graphql endpoint lived at `/graphl` but with ingress-nginx all traffic would be sent to `/api/graphql` thus 404'ing.

The fix for me was to add a [global prefix within NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix#global-prefix) of "api" and manually set the graphql path to be `/api/graphql`.

You could alternatively use ingress-nginx rewrites to remove the `/api/` from routes sent to the backend via [ingress-nginx rewrite targets](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)